# How can I include html page into page content?

Tags: sapui5

My target is include a documentation page into a sap.m.Page. 
I have a sap.m.Page into XML view:

```
<Page id="idPageSidebar" title="" showNavButton="false" navButtonPress="doBack">
        <content>
           //here I want visualize myDocumentation.html page    
        </content>
    </Page>
```

I have myDocumentation.html into a directory of my project.
How I can include it into a sap.m.Page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the core:HTML control and add the content via AJAX 
here an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/C4FW7/

```
      <App>
     <Page title="SAPUI5 App">
         <core:HTML id="html" content="hello"/>
     </Page>
  </App>
```

```
sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
    onInit: function(){
         var that=this;
         $.get( "/8rmAU/show/light", function( data ) {
            that.getView().byId('html').setContent(data);
        });
    }
});
```